# Asynchronous queries in a web app, using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, asynchronous

In a web application, the Session is only available in the current thread.

Does anyone have any tips for executing queries through NHibernate in a new asynchronous thread?

For example, how could I make something like this work:

```
public void Page_Load()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => FooBarRepository.Save(new FooBar()));
}
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue. The NHibernate ISession is stored in the HttpContext which isn't available in asynchronous methods. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why do you store the session in HttpContext if you want it to live longer than the HttpContext?

Comment: Because that is standard practice in a web app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a session context that's smart enough for non web context.  But more importantly, the new thread should have it's own session.

You can use something like the following:

```
private ISession threadSession
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            return (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items["THREAD_SESSION"];
        }

        return (ISession)AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetData("THREAD_SESSION" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
    set
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items["THREAD_SESSION"] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("THREAD_SESSION"
                +Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are not thread-safe.  IOW you'll run into issues sooner or later if you create a session on one thread and use it from another.  Create a new session on your background thread and close it before your background thread finishes.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
public void Page_Load()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => NHibernateSessionFactory.GetSession().Save(new FooBar()));
}
```

Comment: This can cause memory/connetionpool leaks